# How add syntax highlighting to the code view in Joomla 3

Tags: editing

I am trying to find a way to add **syntax highlighting to the code view tab** when editing an article in the Joomla administrator interface. By default it's all black text, no line numbers and no indenting so it's very difficult to see start and end tags when looking at my html code.  I don’t want to add syntax highlighting to text in an article, I just need it when looking at the code view tab when creating/editing articles.

I am using JCE (free version) as my default editor.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The free version of JCE does not support that, but Joomla's built-in TinyMCE does. Moreover, the built-in CodeMirror editor in Joomla! 3 does syntax highlighting.

If you find that specific users spend most of their time editing raw HTML you can tell them to click on their profile at the top-right corner and switch their browser either to TinyMCE or CodeMirror.

There are even plugins ([like this](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/editor-switcher/) -- I have NOT personally tried it) which allow you to switch the editor on-the-fly, without being lost in redirections. I think that explaining to your editors how to switch their editor using such a plugin would be the best solution for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to see syntax highlighting when you switch-off the editor? I don't think switching-off the JCE editor can provide syntax highlighting, as at that moment you use no editor.

However JCE has a plugin to switch to source code editor with syntax highlighting - but I don't remember if this is included with the free version of the editor or if you have to purchase the JCE Editor Pro. If I have to use [**JCE editor**](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net), then I always install the Pro version.

Comment: Using the JCE editor I can switch between the Editor tab and the (source) Code tab.  I would like to enable syntax highlighting in the (source) Code tab.
I think this is only available in the Pro version of JCE and as we are a very small charity we can't afford to get that :-(  
I was therefore wondering is there is some other way of getting syntax highlighting.